# Adding rows to an excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am new to python and I'm working on a code to automate adding rows with values in an excel sheet that contains data from multiple table structures. The the columns had things like entity name, entity id, table column name, column type, and type mode. I am needing to add new table columns to ever table.

I am trying to pull distinct table names and table ids to create a row for a new table column. When I print the new row to make sure it works it just give me all unique entity names and ids in one cell. How do I create a row for each value that matches the right table information. This is what I have below?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('date_test.xlsx')

entity_id = pd.unique(df['Entity ID'])
entity_name = pd.unique(df['Entity name'])
activated = 'TRUE'
type1 = 'bool'
type2 = 'date'
type_mode = 'Required'

new_row = []

for i in entity_id:
    new_row = { 'Business Name' : ['is_active'],
                'Entity ID' : entity_id,
                'Entity name' : entity_name,
                'Activated' : activated,
                'Type' : type1,
                'Type mode' : type_mode}

    print(new_row)
```

I am new to Python and have only taught myself recently. I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it and when I try to research I find things for other problems. The result of me printing the new row to test it looks like below:

```
 {'Business Name': ['is_active'], 
  'Entity ID': array(['680293be', 'a7e61af3', '9653d173',  'e96f789e', 'ab35ff16', '5b01ff4a', '56c759d3', '85d95d42', '3b2s878s'], dtype=object),
  'Entity name': array(['date_period_map_dim', 'calendar_year_dim', 'market_year_dim', 'fiscal_year_dim', 'month_dim', 'period_dim', 'period_type_dim', 'shipping_scheduling_calendar_dim', 'date_dim'], dtype=object), 
  'Activated': 'TRUE', 'Type': 'bool', 'Type mode': 'Required'}
```

I have also formed it as a list and it just changes the format. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve? Please provide a [mre] and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following method to add your new_row list to the end of the dataFrame as a new row

```
# example new row as a list to be added
data_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

# add your list to the end of the dataframe as a new row
df.loc[len(df)] = d_list
```

this will add a new row entry to your existing dataframe. just make sure the list you're trying to add contains same number of entries as your dataframe columns and also follows the columns order.